# Как выделить тысячные доли числа в строке точками?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Нужно сделать разделения, к примеру, числа 15600 точками, чтобы получилось 15.600.

У меня есть input и туда пользователь вводит сумму. Нужно чтобы тысячи разделялись точкой. + добавлялась надпись руб.

Я не могу понять как это сделать. У меня есть код, который я пытался сделать:

```
$('#lolkek').on('change', function () {
var $val = $(this).val();
var $string = '';
for(i = 0; i < $val.length; i++) {
if(i == 2) $string += '.';
 $string += $val[i];
  $(this).val($string)
}
});
```

Но он не работает так, как мне нужно в точности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лови

```js
var x = 15600;

function addCommas(nStr) {
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}

console.log(addCommas(x));
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/379cdvt1/
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) с указанием нужной локали (например, в de-DE используется точка. В ru-RU - пробел). Если нужно просто разбить на группы под текущую локаль - вызывайте без указания локали:

```js
console.log( (10000000).toLocaleString("de-DE") ); // "10.000.000"
console.log( (10000000).toLocaleString() );        // в текущей локали
```

Answer (score 1):

**Простое решение (понятное для новичков):**

На вход функции подаётся числовая строка. Если нужно подавать число, то пишем так:
`insertPoints('' + 15600);`

```js
function insertPoints(s)
{
 //переворачиваем строку наоборот:
 function reverseString(s)
 {
  return s.split('').reverse().join('')
 }

 s = reverseString(s);
 //следующая строка выбирает 2 или 3 цифры
 //и объединяет все значения полученного массива в строку:
 s = s.match(/\d{2,3}/g).join('.');
 s = reverseString(s);
 return s
}

console.log(insertPoints('15600344999') + ' руб.');
console.log(insertPoints('15600344') + ' руб.');
console.log(insertPoints('15600') + ' руб.');
```