# Разделение числа на точки js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Подскажите,как разделить чиcла на точки JS.Спасибо Например:
1.000.000
100.000
10.000
1.000
И вернуть число

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вернуть куда? Откуда?

Comment: Можно записать число как `1_000_000`. Не точки, но наглядно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выделить тысячные доли числа в строке точками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839220/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)